# KDE is slow and crashy from SDDM to KWin to Plasma to Dolphin

Tags: performance, crash, power-management, kde, lag

After updating my Arch system, everything by KDE started breaking, from SDDM taking almost 50s to start up to compositing issues. I've tried removing `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` and resetting settings, to no avail. Even the battery plasmoid is showing no batteries available. How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a week trying all kinds of fixes, to no avail. It turns out that the issue is with UPower.

Everything in KDE relies on it for some unknown reason. I found that `upower -d` failed to output anything, so I checked that `upowerd` was running, via systemd. It was not, and had crashed on start.

I tried manually running it via

```
sudo /usr/lib/upowerd --verbose
```

The output said the `libplist` dependency was missing. I checked via `yay libplist`, and found that I had the git version installed from the AUR. Upon installing `extra/libplist`, which replaced the git version,  both `sudo /usr/lib/upowerd --verbose` and `sudo systemctl start upowerd` worked with no issues.

It was like a miracle. After a quick reboot (SDDM launched super fast), every trace of lag and crash was gone from every part of KDE. Just like that.

As you can probably tell, I wrote this question for my answer. I hope this helps you one way or another. Good luck fixing your system!

*Note to self: check back here if this ever happens again :)*